# Suddenly the footer is anchored to the bottom of the screen, instead of being anchored to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

When testing out the webpage in question, the footer is anchored and displays on the bottom of the screen. The requirement is that it to be anchored to the bottom of the page.

Using the same footer code and CSS on other webpages as well. I didn't face any issues like this when testing on those.

The issue arose just now only on this webpage, when using the "inspect" function on Google Chrome, to test for the responsiveness.

Cleared browser cache and restarted the browser. The issue still remains.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* The footer is fixed to the bottom of the page */

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-height:800px) {
  footer {
    position: static;
  }
  header {
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
}

.footer-distributed {
  background-color: #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font: bold 16px sans-serif;
  padding: 50px 50px 60px 50px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-left,
.footer-distributed .footer-center,
.footer-distributed .footer-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}


/* Footer left */

.footer-distributed .footer-left {
  width: 30%;
}

.footer-distributed h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  font-size: 72px;
  margin: 0;
}


/* The company logo */

.footer-distributed .footer-left img {
  width: 30%;
}

.footer-distributed h3 span {
  color: #e0ac1c;
}


/* Footer links */

.footer-distributed .footer-links {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name {
  color: #8f9296;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
}


/* Footer Center */

.footer-distributed .footer-center {
  width: 35%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i {
  background-color: #33383b;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 42px;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i.fa-envelope {
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 38px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 2;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p a {
  color: #e0ac1c;
  text-decoration: none;
  ;
}


/* Footer Right */

.footer-distributed .footer-right {
  width: 30%;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about {
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #92999f;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about span {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}


/* Here is the code for Responsive Footer */


/* You can remove below code if you don't want Footer to be responsive */

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .footer-distributed .footer-left,
  .footer-distributed .footer-center,
  .footer-distributed .footer-right {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .footer-distributed .footer-center i {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer-distributed">

  <div class="footer-left">
    <img src="img/footerlogo.jpg">
    <h1>Pear</h1>
    <p class="footer-links">
      <a href="Index.html">Home</a> |
      <a href="PearStore.html">Store</a> |
      <a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a> |
      <a href="News.html">News</a> |
      <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a> |
      <a href="AboutUs.html">About</a>
    </p>
    <p class="footer-company-name">© 2020 Pear Technologies Pvt. Ltd.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-center">
    <div>
      <p><span>No.555, Sri Jayawardanapura Road,</span> Colombo, Sri Lanka.</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p>+94 11-2000000</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="mailto:support@pear.lk">support@pear.lk</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-right">
    <p class="footer-company-about"> <span>Our Company</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
    <div class="footer-icons">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="img/facebookicon.png" height="30"></a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="img/twittericon.png" height="30"></a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"><img src="img/instagramicon.png" height="30"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="img/youtubeicon.png" height="30"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Why does your footer have a fixed position ? It should be relative to the page . Try removing the fixed postition and tell me what happens .

Comment: `@media (max-height:800px)` is setting `footer` position to `static`. Probably, when you are opening developer tools with `inspect`, your viewport  width is reduced (under 800) which is why you are facing this issue.

Comment: I'm not experiencing your issue. The footer is never anchored to the bottom of the screen as you're describing. I tried with Chrome and Firefox.